# Use of undefined constant custom_pagination?

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a theme on a second wordpress directory on my server, but when i go to put the (perfect) theme on the main site directory, it shows me some errors that in the "test-design" directory didn't exist.

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant custom_pagination - assumed 'custom_pagination' in /web/htdocs/**********/home/wp-content/themes/********/page-templates/page-news.php on line 76
```

actually there's a name of a fucntion that in the other directory worked fine. Any ideas?

I even change the PHP version of my entire site but... nothing

Answer (score 0):

This seems to remove the error

```
<?php custom_pagination($custom_query->max_num_pages,"",$paged); ?>
```